# Convention for describing larger or smaller wire awg

Tags: wire, awg

With wire awg, a larger number means a smaller wire.  What is the proper convention for making comparisons between wire awg?  For example if you you say it a wire needs to be larger than 12awg, is that more or less copper?  Should the word larger/smaller be avoided and lower/higher used and clarification be asked when they are used?

Comment: Just say "bigger wire" instead of "bigger AWG".

Comment: I always go "A larger gauge than 12AWG". Those familiar with AWG know this will be 11 or "smaller". Those that don't know it needs to have a larger diameter than 12AWG

Answer (score 1):

I see the point of confusion but have never given it much thought. Lower/higher is a LOT more confusing than larger/smaller.

If someone said "larger/smaller than 12AWG", to me that would mean more/less copper, so a numerically lower/higher AWG. I probably think this way since "larger" and "smaller" have physicality to them; A wire can be physically larger or smaller. In short, "AWG" is synonymous with "size" or "diameter".

If they said a "higher/lower AWG", that would give me pause unless the context was clear. "The current is too high, you need a  wire gauge."  it really doesn't matter what the relative adjective is. You know what it is trying to say. But I don't think I've had anyone communicate AWG to me using this method.

But you probably should just say wire/conductor diameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would use "heavier" or "lighter" instead.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=American_wire_gauge&action=edit&section=1):

> The diameter of a № ''n'' AWG wire is determined, for gauges smaller than 00 (36 to 0), according to the following formula:
> $$ d_n = 0.005~\mathrm{inch} \times 92^\frac{36 - n}{39} = 0.127~\mathrm{mm} \times 92^\frac{36 - n}{39} $$

It's hard to see where the difficulty lies if you can raise 92 to fractional powers in your head. :^)

Comment: Not so easy, mostly. 36 gauge is easy though.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany "Hmmmmm. You haven't sized your wire properly. You need an easier AWG."

Comment: "Thicker/thinner" would also work.